# How to make display to have frame around to avoid ball getting out of display?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I am trying to make simple game with ball but how to make display to have frame around to avoid ball getting out of display ?
I want to have small hole in that frame so ball eventually can get out. I done this like putting couple rectangles ( with width or height 1px and other dimension is larger ) around display but when ball has large speed it pass through wall. Is there better solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add physics body to the frame so that the ball will not pass through it

```
local topWall = display.newRect(0,0,display.contentWidth,2)
physics.addBody( topWall, "static", { friction = 0.5, bounce = 0 } )
```

Don't forget to start the physics engine "`physics.start()`" on the top of your code

P.S just modify the the `topFrame`and create another three walls on both side and on the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

just make rect wider like 300px.

also you can try to set parameter ball.isBullet = true it will tell physics engine to keep eye on ball to avoid getting it through walls