# how to stop objects from being dragged off screen

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I am using this code to move my object

```
 function myObject( event )
    if event.phase == "began" then

        monkey.markX = monkey.x    -- store x location of object
       -- monkey.markY = monkey.y    -- store y location of object

    elseif event.phase == "moved" then

        local x = (event.x - event.xStart) + monkey.markX
      --  local y = (event.y - event.yStart) + monkey.markY
        if monkey.x <= screenLeft then
            print("left")
        monkey.x = 250
        else
        end

       monkey.x = x    -- move object based on calculations above
    end

    return true

end
```

The problem is that with this code the character can be dragged off screen, i dont want that to happen. 
An explanation with code on how to stop this form happening would be appreciated

Comment: This has been already asked, Check [this][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26823313/how-to-make-display-to-have-frame-around-to-avoid-ball-getting-out-of-display/26856716#26856716

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a mistake

```
 local x = (event.x - event.xStart) + monkey.markX
 if monkey.x <= screenLeft then
     print("left")
     monkey.x = 250
 else
 end
 monkey.x = x
```

No mater your conditional the last thing you do is "monkey.x = x" try:

```
local offset = 0
local x = (event.x - event.xStart) + monkey.markX
if monkey.x <= screenLeft then
    print("left")
    monkey.x = screenLeft + offset
else
    monkey.x = x
end
```

Also, you should use 'screenLeft' instead of 250. You have the boundary, keep it consistent. If you want it to bump back a little then you use the 'offset'

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is make the monkey a dynamic physics body, and then put essential for static walls on the outside of the screen. This should theoretically prevent the user from dragging the monkey outside of a given space.

Another way you might me able to do that is to have a runtime event check if the monkey is outside of a current area, to move them to a different area.

For example:

```
 function(checkMonkey)
    if monkey.x >= 0 then
    monkey.x = a default number
    end
    --repeat that with x as 250 (or whatever the x height is), y as 0, as y as 400 (or what ever the y height is)
 end --function ends the checkMonkey function
```

Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", checkMonkey)

' Hope the code helps. Either way should work, but they might involve a bit of tweaking to work in your app

Comment: putting walls will do the trick. But I dont agree on checking the its x and y, what its anchor points is in 0.5. The object will still go outside the screen.